Uniformly estimating $\int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,1)}|Ux\wedge Vx|\,dx$, for skew-symmetric matrices $U$, $V$, with $|x\wedge y|^2=|x|^2|y|^2-<x,y>^2$
Let $U,V$ be two $n\times n$ skew-symmetric, linearly independent matrices.
I want to estimate the following
$$
\int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,1)} \left| Ux \, \wedge \, Vx \right| \, dx,
$$
where $|x \wedge y| := \sqrt{|x|^2 |y|^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2 }$.
I want to obtain upper and lower bounds uniformly in $(n, U, V)$, or you can compute it directly to get an expression, and you can assume $n$ is large.
I can only estimate it under the condition
$$
UV + VU =0,\quad U^2 = V^2.
$$
since in this case the above integral becomes
$$
\int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,1)} |Ux|^2 \, dx.
$$
I can compute it by a orthogonal transformation. See this problem (How to estimate the integral?)
I also want to know what is the relation between this integral and probability theory.
In general, if I have $m$ ($m\le n$) linearly independent matrices $U_1,\cdots,U_m$, the problem is
$$
\int_{B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,1)} \left| U_1 x \, \wedge \, \cdots \, \wedge \, U_m x \right| \, dx,
$$
where $U_1 x \, \wedge \, \cdots \, \wedge \, U_m x$ is the Gram determinant of $U_1 x,\cdots, U_m x$.

A trivial lower bound is given by zero. For $U=V$ this bound is attained. In order to get a better bound, you would need additional assumptions.

@daw Thanks,  they are linearly independent.
